# Cannot refresh data in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with filter functionality on datatable. I am stuck at a point where i want to return my all data back after filter options remove. Can you please tell me how to revert back all data in datatable.

i am using this code to filter data (and working great)

```
var dataTable = $("#my-div").DataTable();
dataTable.column(2).search("search-value").draw();
```

and for retrive all data (Not working)

```
dataTable.draw();
```

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide empty string argument to [`column().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29) API method to remove search query.

```
dataTable.column(2).search('').draw();
```